# how to traverse a massive dataframe pair-wisely and store the value in a n*n matrix?

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

**Problem Description:**

I have a dataset which is about  *35 millons rows*  and  *10 columns* .

I want to calculate the distance between two rows, which the distancefunction like `distance(row1,row2)`, and then store the value in a huge matrix.

The operations totally needed are nearly *6*10^15*, which i think is very huge.

**What I've tried :**

1. upload datafile to HDFS
2. read data as dataframe
3. `df.collect()` and get a `array1 :array[Row]`
4. traverse `array1` pair-wisely and calculate distance
5. store the `distance(rowi,rowj)` in *matrix(i,j)*

**Scala code :**

```
val array1 = df.collect()
val l = array1.length 
for(i <-0 until array.length){
    for(j <-i+1 until array.length){
             val vd = Vectors.dense(i,j,distance(array(i),array(j)))
```

I want to save each value in Vector like above, and add it to RDD/Dataframe.

But the only way i've searched is by using `union`.I think it's not good enough.

**So there are three questions need to be solved:**

1. `collect` is an action function, `df.collect()` will throw Exception
   `java.lang.OutOf.MemoryError : Java heap space`. Can this be avoided?
2. As soon as i get a `distance(rowi,rowj)`, i want to store it, how?
3. Can I store the final matrix in HDFS and read it as a matrix in python?

ps: If above all can't be solved, which new idea can i use?

Any answer will help me a lot ,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#indexedrowmatrix IndexedRowMatrix. An IndexedRowMatrix is similar to a RowMatrix but with meaningful row indices.
You can design your algorithm based in this APi.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying your approach.I think it will work well. Later, I will update my solution here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `https://github.com/ma7555/evalify` (disclaimer: I am the owner)